# Parquet Size Difference

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0, apache-spark-3.0

Before posting this question, I went through similar questions e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141949/different-size-of-same-parquet-file-in-spark)
but didn't find convincing response, subsequent to my issue.

Actually, in my existing ETL code, I have upgraded Spark 2.3.1 to Spark 3.4, along with hadoop,hive, yarn transitive dependencies.

*Code is unchanged.
Source XML feeds are same.*

ETL is processing source XML and writing Parquet with LZO compression codec and putting them into S3 bucket.

My issue is this, that when I compare "**Parquet Generated By Spark 2.3.1**" with "**Parquet Generated By Spark 3.4**", then, I observed size difference of 2-to-3-KBs.

*Please note Code is unchanged.
Source XML feeds are same.*

In some cases, either "**Parquet Generated By Spark 2.3.1**" is having 2-to-3-KBs size less than "**Parquet Generated By Spark 3.4**" and in some cases, it is opposite.

So, my confusion is this that, is this because LZO compression behaves differently among Spark 2.3.1 and Spark 3.4 ?

or is it due to the difference of Parquet Encoder  between Spark 2.3.1 & Spark 3.4 ?

Please suggest?

Comment: Spark 2.3.1 released June 8, 2018
Spark 3.4.0 released April 13, 2023

Rained a lot between versions, so it is difficult to isolate which change caused the behavious... Detecting the first version where the difference happens, may be a good starting point to find out what happened. Then, I would dig into Spark release notes

Comment: Why is taht difference of 2-3 KBs so important to dive into the Spark implementation? Just curiosity

Comment: it'll be driven by the parquet version: look at the different versions then see the changelog between them. there's a lot more to efficient column storage than just compression codecs, in particular metadata about row chunks used on query time to decide when to skip them, how to efficiently scan them etc.

Comment: @DanielPerezEfremova: Just trying to get into the root cause lies behind that difference of 2-3 KBs. so that I can convince my own reasoning side.

Comment: @stevel that point just explain one side... --> "In some cases, either "Parquet Generated By Spark 2.3.1" is having 2-to-3-KBs size less than "Parquet Generated By Spark 3.4" and in some cases, it is opposite."

Comment: what was the difference between dataframes when differences raised in both cases? Dataframe rows, data types, partitions, encoding, etc? It could point out which release caused the difference

Comment: @DanielPerezEfremova Same build was tested on both versions of Spark. Even dataset , along with data type, partition scheme, encoding was exactly same. only change was EMR version upgrade from 5.17 to 6.12. I observed Amazon had done it's own version of Spark, instead of open source version of Spark. May be that's the reason, why Parquet size was differing.