# Spark + Parquet + Snappy: Overall compression ratio loses after spark shuffles data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, snappy

Commmunity!

Please help me understand how to get better compression ratio with Spark?

Let me describe case:

1. I have dataset, let's call it **product** on HDFS which was imported using Sqoop ImportTool as-parquet-file using codec **snappy**. As result of import, I have 100 files with total *46 GB* du, files with diffrrent size (min 11MB, max 1.5GB, avg ~ 500MB). Total count of records a little bit more than *8 billions* with *84 columns*
2. I'm doing simple read/repartition/write with Spark using **snappy** as well and as result I'm getting:

~**100 GB** output size with the same files count, same codec, same count and same columns.

Code snippet:

```
val productDF = spark.read.parquet("/ingest/product/20180202/22-43/")

productDF
.repartition(100)
.write.mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Overwrite)
.option("compression", "snappy")
.parquet("/processed/product/20180215/04-37/read_repartition_write/general")
```

3. Using parquet-tools I have looked into random files from both ingest and processed and they looks as below:

ingest:

```
creator:                        parquet-mr version 1.5.0-cdh5.11.1 (build ${buildNumber}) 
extra:                          parquet.avro.schema = {"type":"record","name":"AutoGeneratedSchema","doc":"Sqoop import of QueryResult","fields"

and almost all columns looks like
AVAILABLE: OPTIONAL INT64 R:0 D:1

row group 1:                    RC:3640100 TS:36454739 OFFSET:4 

AVAILABLE:                       INT64 SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:172743 SZ:370515/466690/1.26 VC:3640100 ENC:RLE,PLAIN_DICTIONARY,BIT_PACKED ST:[min: 126518400000, max: 1577692800000, num_nulls: 2541633]
```

processed:

```
creator:                        parquet-mr version 1.5.0-cdh5.12.0 (build ${buildNumber}) 
extra:                          org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.metadata = {"type":"struct","fields"

AVAILABLE:                      OPTIONAL INT64 R:0 D:1
...

row group 1:                    RC:6660100 TS:243047789 OFFSET:4 

AVAILABLE:                       INT64 SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:4122795 SZ:4283114/4690840/1.10 VC:6660100 ENC:BIT_PACKED,PLAIN_DICTIONARY,RLE ST:[min: -2209136400000, max: 10413820800000, num_nulls: 4444993]
```

In other hand, without repartition or using coalesce - size remains close to ingest data size.

4. Going forward, I did following:

   - read dataset and write it back with

     ```
     productDF
       .write.mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Overwrite)
       .option("compression", "none")
       .parquet("/processed/product/20180215/04-37/read_repartition_write/nonewithoutshuffle")
     ```
   - read dataset, repartition and write it back with

     ```
     productDF
       .repartition(500)
       .write.mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Overwrite)
       .option("compression", "none")
       .parquet("/processed/product/20180215/04-37/read_repartition_write/nonewithshuffle")
     ```

As result: **80 GB** without and  **283 GB** with repartition with same # of output files

80GB parquet meta example:

```
AVAILABLE:                       INT64 UNCOMPRESSED DO:0 FPO:456753 SZ:1452623/1452623/1.00 VC:11000100 ENC:RLE,PLAIN_DICTIONARY,BIT_PACKED ST:[min: -1735747200000, max: 2524550400000, num_nulls: 7929352]
```

283 GB parquet meta example:

```
AVAILABLE:                       INT64 UNCOMPRESSED DO:0 FPO:2800387 SZ:2593838/2593838/1.00 VC:3510100 ENC:RLE,PLAIN_DICTIONARY,BIT_PACKED ST:[min: -2209136400000, max: 10413820800000, num_nulls: 2244255]
```

It seems, that parquet itself (with encoding?) much reduce size of data even without uncompressed data. How ? :)

I tried to read  uncompressed 80GB, repartition and write back - I've got my 283 GB

- The first question for me is why I'm getting bigger size after spark repartitioning/shuffle?
- The second is how to efficiently shuffle data in spark to benefit parquet encoding/compression if there any?

In general, I don't want that my data size growing after spark processing, even if I didn't change anything.

Also, I failed to find, is there any *configurable compression rate* for snappy, e.g. -1 ... -9? As I know, gzip has this, but what is the way to control this rate in Spark/Parquet writer?

Appreciate for any help!

Thanks!

Comment: [Why are Spark Parquet files for an aggregate larger than the original?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38153935/8371915)

Comment: Thanks @user8371915 ! Now I understand why the size is different, I tried repartition by some (luckily found) column of my dataset and as result I've got 80Gb instead of 250Gb constantly. 
But the second question, what is the common steps to figure out the bullet to solve this kind of problems. I tried to look into `DataFrameStatFunctions`, but I'm not strong enough to find them useful. May somebody advice how to work with data organization problem?

Comment: In my particular dataset case, Sqoop import result is quite small ~50Gb of compressed data, I assume because Sqoop imported partition has ordered range of primary keys, e.g. first partition has ids from 1 to 100000, and data inside partition is closer each other and have better encoding/compression ratio with parquet and snappy.

Comment: I tried to find a way how to archive the same data organization using `DataFrame` API, but found that range partitioner will be available starting from 2.3.0 as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995699/how-to-define-partitioning-of-dataframe. Will try down to RDD level and implement custom range partitioner for testing with data distribution.

Answer (score 5):

when you call `repartition(n)` on a dataframe you are doing a round-robin partitioning. Any data locality that existed prior to repartitioning is gone entropy has gone up. So run length and dictionary encoders as well as compression codecs don't really have much to work with.

so when you do you repartition you need to use `repartition (n, col)` version. give it a good column that would preserve data locality.

Also, since you are probably optimizing your sqooped tables for downstream jobs you can `sortWithinPartition` for faster scans.

`df.repartition(100, $"userId").sortWithinPartitions("userId").write.parquet(...)`

Comment: " is gone entropy has gone up" what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

it's more to do with how parquet compresses data. In a nutshell if you are writing a 1000 rows into a single file. Consider a column with strings, the parquet uses dictionary encoding to store them.

If all 1000 strings are different, then it needs to use larger dictionary encoding (with 1000 key map) -- Usually referred as large entropy
If all 1000 strings are same, then you need to use smaller dictionary (with only one key map) -- Usually referred as smaller entropy

Since larger dictionary leads to more data (more entropy case), it leads to larger size on the disk.