# Spark shuffle write: why shuffle write data is much bigger than input data read from hdfs?

Tags: apache-spark

I am doing a data cleaning with very simple logic.

```
    val inputData= spark.read.parquet(inputDataPath)
    val viewMiddleTable = sdk70000DF.where($"type" === "0").select($"field1", $"field2", $field3)
      .groupBy($"field1", $"field2", $field3)
      .agg(count(lit(1)))
```

Read parquet data from hdfs, filter, select target fields and group by all fields, then count.

When I check the UI, below things happended.

Input 81.2 GiB
Shuffle Write 645.7 GiB

[image]

How can the shuffle write data so much bigger than the originally read data?
It should be just a little expanded in this situation.
Can anyone explain this? Thanks.

Comment: This is because parquet is encoded and compressed. The shuffle occur after the data is inflated

Comment: I referred this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847660/spark-parquet-snappy-overall-compression-ratio-loses-after-spark-shuffles-d?rq=1

and made some optimization as below:

select...
      .repartition(1000, $"field1")
      .sortWithinPartitions()
.group...

New input and shuffle write data is：input 40.2Gib，shuffle write 77.3Gib，shuffle write/input is always about 2. Much better than the unoptimized , which is 40.7 vs. 334.9, with a ratio of 8.
The shuffle data should still be parquet+snappy, but how data organized may affected the shuffle write data size. Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Deserialization of parquet files that are columnar and compressed, means they expand in size in memory or on disk(spill). It's a well-known aspect of Spark - as you candidly observe yourself now.